# Error on login everytime

Tags: 16.04, login

I get this error each time I login [see attached screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kld5e.png).
I am using Ubuntu Studio 16.04.1 and have the following desktop environments installed :-

- Ubuntu Studio session(Pre-installed)
- Xcfe(Pre-installed)
- Genome
- KDE Plasma
- Ubuntu (original "unflavoured" gui)

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to `fsck` (file system check) as your first step.

- boot to the GRUB menu
- choose Advanced Options
- choose root access
- type `sudo fsck -f /`
- run fsck more than once if there are errors
- type `reboot` when done